# Is there a way to remove prefixes/suffixes and contractions in Mallet

Tags: mallet

I recently started to use Mallet from UMass.  I looked to see if there was a way to remove prefixes/suffixes and contractions with a command, just like the stop-words has a command, however I didn't find any information about it.  If Mallet can do this, can someone point me in the right direction. And if it cannot, but there is something else you know of that can do this, can you point me in that direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do some computational-linguistic preprocessing to your corpus (e.g. stemming or lemmatising) before running Mallet on it.

I am not aware of a way to do this inside Mallet (and it is heavily language dependent). Maybe you can write an input filter, but I'd keep it outside Mallet.